# how to remove EOF, which is getting appended to last word

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-c++, eof

I would like to remove only the EOF character from the last word in paragraph of text. The EOF is getting appended to the last word and we are unable to read the entire text. Is there any workaround for this issue ?

Comment: What language, what code are you using?

Comment: And how are you reading the file?  If you use the text methods they won't grab the EOF character.

Comment: Its VB script used to 'getText()' from one of the textbox using one of the automation tool.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed it as EOL and If you retrieved it to string ..

```
Dim s as String = .... '--> whatever where you get from
Dim x as Integer
Dim sResult as String = ""

For x=0 to s.Length-1
  If s.substring(x,2) = vbCRLF then  
    x+=1
  Else
    sResult &= s.substring(x,1)
  Endif

Next
```

So you can get `sResult` as String without Paragraph Break

**Updated :**

If you want replace the linefeed ..

```
sResult=sResult.Replace(vbLF,"")
```

Comment: I did more troubleshooting into this, and found that last character is a Line Feed (vbLf), however I was unable to substring this as the word with LineFeed simply truncates.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the linefeed, however If i do a replace, the word along with linefeed is getting replaced.
Same effect with remove or replace.

Comment: it removes the entire word along with linefeed

Comment: just do the updated answer .. sResult = s.replace(vbLF,"") .. s is your source string